# What event happens when Requerying ListBox?

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have form with several sub forms.

When user change combo box value located in main form, I want every subform to refresh using Requery Method. It worked as I want.

Except in one of the subform. I'm adding a listbox and also put a textbox to SUM one of the column in the listbox.

I've create vba code to calculate the column. Put the code in Current event of the subform, and several other events in the subform. Also in listbox AfterUpdate event. But it doesnt seem to work.

```
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim ctl As Control

Set ctl = Me.lstBox

j = ctl.ListCount - 1

Me.txtTotal = 0

For i = 1 To j
    Me.txtTotal = Me.txtTotal + ctl.Column(3, i)
Next i

Me.txtTotal = Format(Me.txtTotal, "#,##")
```

Add a breakpoint in sub procedure name (such as Form_Current, etc.), but it seems not firing up.
Where should I put this code?

EDITED
I try put the code in ComboBox AfterUpdate event, it worked.
But if there is another approach, I still can give a vote.

Comment: This sounds weird.. why is this subform acting differently?

Comment: Are there linked fields between form and subforms? I ma not sure about the exact behavior but a subform should auto-requery when the main form is requeried when there are linked fields, but it may not requery when there aren't any. If the subform does not requery then its onCurrent event is not firing.

Comment: @SunKnight0 In every record source of subforms, i refer to main form's combobox value. I also add Requery code for each subforms in AfterUpdate event in Main Form's ComboBox. So evrytime i update the value in ComboBox, everything will refresh. So i dont need a linked fields for this. I have put the above code in After Update event of Main Form's ComboBox, and it worked now.